# How to get only certain data in pie amcharts?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pie-chart, amcharts

I'm using Amcharts in angular 2. I'm displaying a pie graph and the data is being displayed in percentages. However I want to display data according to the user selected percentage. Like user enters 50, I want to display data above 50%. Can somebody help?

The following is my code sample.

```
this.supplierChart = this.AmCharts.makeChart("suppchartdiv", {
   "hideCredits":true,
   "title": 'Supplier Share',
   "type": "pie",
   "theme": "none",
   "dataProvider": supp_data,
   "labelText": "",
   "valueField": "quantity",
   "titleField": "Supplier",
   "balloon":{
   "fixedPosition":true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

Here supp_data is some JSON data for chart input

Comment: just filter the supp_data and render the chart

Comment: @ShivajiVarma Filtering the data is resulting in the redistribution of the new data. Hence the values are changing. I don't want this to happen. Can we avoid this? I want to show the original percentages even after filtering

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply hide the slices that are below a threshold, set an [`alphaField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#alphaField) in your chart, then iterate through the chart's [`chartData`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#chartData) array and check the [`percents`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Slice#percents) property and selectively set the slice's alphaField property to 0 if it falls beneath your user's threshold. For example:

```
  var thresholdValue = /* get value from user somewhere */
  if (!thresholdValue) {
    chart.dataProvider.forEach(function(dataItem) {
      dataItem[chart.alphaField] = 1;
    })
  }
  else {
    chart.chartData.forEach(function(dataItem, idx) {
      if (dataItem.percents <= thresholdValue) {
        dataItem.dataContext[chart.alphaField] = 0;
        // or
        // chart.dataProvider[idx][chart.alphaField] = 0;
      }
    })
  }
  chart.validateData(); //update chart
```

If you're using the angular plugin, you can likely wrap this logic inside the updateChart callback.

Vanilla JS demo below:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 501.9
  }, {
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 301.9
  }, {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 201.1
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 165.8
  }, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "litres": 139.9
  }, {
    "country": "Austria",
    "litres": 128.3
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "litres": 99
  }, {
    "country": "Belgium",
    "litres": 60
  }, {
    "country": "The Netherlands",
    "litres": 50
  }],
  "alphaField": "alpha",
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
  "balloon": {
    "fixedPosition": true
  }
});

document.getElementById("update").addEventListener('click', function() {
  var thresholdValue = +document.getElementById('percent').value;
  if (!thresholdValue) {
    chart.dataProvider.forEach(function(dataItem) {
      dataItem[chart.alphaField] = 1;
    })
  }
  else {
    chart.chartData.forEach(function(dataItem, idx) {
      if (dataItem.percents <= thresholdValue) {
        dataItem.dataContext[chart.alphaField] = 0;
        // or
        // chart.dataProvider[idx][chart.alphaField] = 0;
      }
      else {
        dataItem.dataContext[chart.alphaField] = 1;
      }
    })
  }
  chart.validateData(); 
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<label>Filter percent value: <input type="text" id="percent"></label><button id="update">Update</button>
```

Comment: There's one glitch in your solution. The graph is not displaying same if the value is given multiple times. Can you say how this can be resolved?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean it doesn't unhide hidden points if a subsequent value is smaller than the first? I added an else clause to my demo. If that doesn't help, can you clarify what's wrong by explaining the steps.

Comment: I got it working by adding an else clause... I'm sorry I forgot to remove my comment after that.